# Why do we randomly get static shocks

Tags: electrostatics, soft-question

Recently, I've been getting random static shocks from touching objects that don't seem to have any electrical current going through them, I was just wondering what causes these shocks as it happens often and never really knew the reason why.

Comment: There is a possible explanation here. https://intranet.birmingham.ac.uk/hr/documents/public/hsu/information/electrical/staticelectricity.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An electric shock needs charge, not current. A lot of charge residing on the surface of something will flow into your body at a touch. This is the shock feeling.

Furthermore, there is nothing random about it. You touch the surface and it transfers it's excess charge, if it has any. It will feel like a shock if there is enough.